# Rows locking when running update statement in production

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering what is the correct solution to the below is.

I have an `UPDATE` statement in T-SQL that needs to be run as a daily task. The procedure will update one bit column in one table. Rows affected is around 30,000.

A pseudo version of the T-SQL

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET BIT_FIELD = [dbo].[FUNCTION](TABLE_NAME.ID)
WHERE -- THIS ISN'T RELEVANT
```

The function that determines true or false basically runs a few checks and hits around 3 other tables. Currently the procedure takes about 30 minutes to run and update 30,000 rows in our development environment. I was expecting this to double on production.

The problem I'm having is that intermittently `TABLE_NAME` table locks up. If I run it in batches of 1000 it seems ok but if I increase this it appears to run fine but eventually the table locks up. The only resolution is to cancel the query which results in no rows being updated.

Please note that the procedure is not wrapped in a TRANSACTION.

If I run each update in a separate `UPDATE` statement would this fix it? What would be a good solution when updating quite a large number of records in a live environment?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you established, is the lock being escalated to a table lock?

Comment: Does the function read from TABLE_NAME as well?

Comment: Hi Martin and JStead. Thanks for the quick response.

In answer to Martin's question.. I haven't. Could I test this by running a simple select against a different column when I think the lock is happening?

JStead - the function does read from TABLE_NAME.

Thanks both

Comment: @TomMiller - You can run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id=<spid_of_other_session>`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks. I'll do some further investigation.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hi Martin. I think it's a full table lock since I see resource_type as object with request_status of wait?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is a full table lock. Could this simply be down to the number of concurrent activities running on the production box?

Comment: @TomMiller - [Generally it will try to escalate to a table lock after acquiring 5,000 row locks so this is expected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx)

Comment: @TomMiller - I am betting that your (dbo.function) call here is a normal scalar. You can probably cut that runtime in half by using an inline scalar function - see http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions

Comment: @QuantumElf nice article; I was going to suggest rewriting the query to use an inline TVF.  Interesting method of mimicing a scalar function.

Comment: I believe I've worked out what was happening: Because the update statement was affecting 30K records which is above the 5K when it reached this cap it was escalating to a full table lock on TABLE_NAME and prevent itself from doing anything since the SET called a function that queries TABLE_NAME so it would never complete. We moved the procedure into a loop updating 1K records each time which worked without any issues.

As an extra bonus I added some non-clustered indexes to some tables included in the query and it now runs in 10 seconds for all 30K records. Awesome! Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the SQL Server Optimizer has probably determined that a table lock is needed to perform the update of your table. You should perform rework on your query so that this table lock will not occur or will have a smaller impact on your users. So in a practical way this means: (a) speed up your query and (b) make sure the table will not lock.
Personally I would consider the following:
1. Create clustered and non-clustered indexes on your tables in order to improve the performance of your query.
2. See if it is possible to not use a function, but instead use joins, they are typically a lot faster.
3. Break up the update in multiple parts and perform these parts separately. You might have an 'or' satement in your 'where' clause, that is a good splitting point, but you can also consider creating a cursor to loop through the table and perform the update at one record at a time.

Comment: Or set up a batch process that updates the first 1000 records, then updates the next 1000, etc. Also the OP should be aware that those types of functions run row by row just like a cursor which is why the update takes so long. Replacing the function with joins or possibly a case statment would likely speed this up to where locking isn't a  concern. A daily task that take 30 minutes is unacceptably slow.